# i want to buy a portable 1TB HDD

Tags: external-hdd

i want to buy a portable 1TB HDD, which should be supportable in Ubuntu as well as Microsoft windows (xp and above). Can any one suggest me a good HDD?

Comment: [No, we can not.](http://askubuntu.com/faq#dontask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu will support any HDD you buy and almost all HDD's available in market mentions compatibility with Windows.

Comment: Unless you have a Western Digital and use the crapware supplied on it to encrypt the disk ;)

Comment: I guess this applies to all vendor specific encryption software that only runs on a specific (non linux) OS ;)

Answer (score 0):

Go with ***Transcend*** *Storejet* (R). It has real value for money plus the compatibilities you're looking for and added features.

Source : My experience :) :)